# My rule is invisible when declared in a sub makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

These are simplified examples of my question.

I have:
Makefile in top/sub/sub/dir:

```
THINGSTODO := dothis

dothis:
    @echo Do cool stuff
```

Main makefile in top dir:

```
all: $(THINGSTODO)
    @echo do important stuff
```

Makefile in the sub dirs get included automatically.

If I run this (make all) I get:
***No rule to make target 'dothis', needed by 'all'.***

My conclusion is that the variable THINGSTODO gets a value but for some reason the rule "dothis" is not visible.

If I place the "dothis" rule in the main makefile it works like a charm.
But I don't want to change the main makefile, I just want to add a rule, in the sub/sub/dir makefile, that is executed before the "all" rule is executed.

I must be missing a vital bit of knowledge to solve this. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

system: Linux 4.18.13-100.fc27.x86_64
make: GNU Make 4.2.1 (Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: "_Makefile in the sub dirs get included automatically_": sure? Can you show the part of your top Makefile that is supposed to do that?

Comment: I''l try to find where it exactly happens but I'm sure it gets included. If I change the THINGSTODO variable I get a different error string (different rule that's missing).

Comment: And if I change the name of the makefile in the sub/sub/dir I get errors it is missing that specific makefile (name of the makefile must be in a specific format to facilitate the auto search).

Comment: Unfortunately, as we cannot see the real code, it is impossible to reproduce your problem. It could be a typo or anything else. Did you try to replace `dothis:` by `$(THINGSTODO):` in your included Makefile, just in case? Anyway, if you really want some help from StackOverflow, you should seriously consider providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I understand, this build system is not made by me and is a bit elaborate, I just want to add to it without changing it. I'll try to make a MCVE from it.